# JSON Array convert to CSV

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv

I'm trying to convert a JSON response to CSV file but I have a problem about arrays
Here is the conversion code to CSV

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents("feed.json");
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$json = $jsonDecoded['results'];
jsonToCsv($json, "feed.csv");

function jsonToCsv ($json, $csvFilePath = false, $boolOutputFile = false) {

    // See if the string contains something
    if (empty($json)) { 
      die("The JSON string is empty!");
    }

    // If passed a string, turn it into an array
    if (is_array($json) === false) {
      $json = json_decode($json, true);
    }

    // If a path is included, open that file for handling. Otherwise, use a temp file (for echoing CSV string)
    if ($csvFilePath !== false) {
      $f = fopen($csvFilePath,'w+');
      if ($f === false) {
        die("Couldn't create the file to store the CSV, or the path is invalid. Make sure you're including the full path, INCLUDING the name of the output file (e.g. '../save/path/csvOutput.csv')");
      }
    }
    else {
      $boolEchoCsv = true;
      if ($boolOutputFile === true) {
        $boolEchoCsv = false;
      }
      $strTempFile = 'feed' . date("U") . ".csv";
      $f = fopen($strTempFile,"w+");
    }

    $firstLineKeys = false;
    foreach ($json as $line) {
      if (empty($firstLineKeys)) {
        $firstLineKeys = array_keys($line);
        fputcsv($f, $firstLineKeys);
        $firstLineKeys = array_flip($firstLineKeys);
      }

      // Using array_merge is important to maintain the order of keys acording to the first element
      fputcsv($f, array_merge($firstLineKeys, $line));
    }
    fclose($f);

    // Take the file and put it to a string/file for output (if no save path was included in function arguments)
    if ($boolOutputFile === true) {
      if ($csvFilePath !== false) {
        $file = $csvFilePath;
      }
      else {
        $file = $strTempFile;
      }

      // Output the file to the browser (for open/save)
      if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
      }
    }
    elseif ($boolEchoCsv === true) {
      if (($handle = fopen($strTempFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
          echo implode(",",$data);
          echo "<br />";
        }
        fclose($handle);
      }
    }

    // Delete the temp file
    unlink($strTempFile);

  }
?>
```

And here is a example of feed.json content

```
 {
   "isError":false,
   "messages":[

   ],
   "results":[
      {
         "part_number_key":"DASDSA",
         "buy_button_rank":1,
         "category_id":11,
         "id":123,
         "brand":"brand",
         "vendor_category_id":null,
         "name":"Name",
         "part_number":"part number",
         "sale_price":12.31,
         "currency":"RON",
         "description":"description",
         "url":"https://www.url.com",
         "warranty":12,
         "general_stock":10,
         "weight":"0",
         "status":1,
         "recommended_price":12.19,
         "images":[
            {
               "url":"https://url.com/images.jpg1",
               "display_type":1
            },
            {
               "url":"https://url.com/images.jpg2",
               "display_type":0
            },
            {
               "url":"https://url.com/images.jpg3",
               "display_type":0
            }
         ],
         "characteristics":[
            {
               "id":8937,
               "value":"value"
            },
            {
               "id":8930,
               "value":"value"
            },
            {
               "id":8927,
               "value":"value"
            },
            {
               "id":8928,
               "value":"value"
            },
            {
               "id":5537,
               "value":"value"
            },
            {
               "id":8932,
               "value":"value"
            },
            {
               "id":8934,
               "value":"value"
            },
            {
               "id":8929,
               "value":"value"
            },
            {
               "id":7235,
               "value":"value"
            },
            {
               "id":6556,
               "value":"value"
            },
            {
               "id":5401,
               "value":"value"
            }
         ],
         "attachments":[

         ],
         "vat_id":1,
         "family":{
            "id":1104,
            "name":"NAME",
            "family_type_id":244
         },
         "start_date":[

         ],
         "estimated_stock":10,
         "reversible_vat_charging":false,
         "min_sale_price":11,
         "max_sale_price":200,
         "offer_details":{
            "id":2484194,
            "warranty_type":null,
            "supply_lead_time":14
         },
         "offer_properties":[

         ],
         "product_measurements":[

         ],
         "availability":[
            {
               "warehouse_id":1,
               "id":3
            }
         ],
         "stock":[
            {
               "warehouse_id":1,
               "value":10
            }
         ],
         "handling_time":[
            {
               "warehouse_id":1,
               "value":0
            }
         ],
         "barcode":[

         ],
         "ean":[

         ],
         "commission":{
            "value":"20.0000",
            "type":"percentage",
            "id":"123",
            "priority":"4",
            "created":"2010-01-16 11:25:02"
         },
         "validation_status":[
            {
               "value":9,
               "description":"Approved documentation",
               "errors":null
            }
         ],
         "offer_validation_status":{
            "value":1,
            "description":"Saleable",
            "errors":null
         },
         "ownership":1,
         "best_offer_sale_price":11,
         "best_offer_recommended_price":11,
         "number_of_offers":1
      },
      {
         "part_number_key":"D3129DKQW",
         "buy_button_rank":1,
         "category_id":456,
         "id":123,
         "brand":"Bluedio",
         "vendor_category_id":null,
         "name":"name",
         "part_number":"part number",
         "sale_price":123,
         "currency":"EUR",
         "description":"description",
         "url":"https://url.com",
         "warranty":24,
         "general_stock":1,
         "weight":"0",
         "status":1,
         "recommended_price":12,
         "images":[
            {
               "url":"https://url.com/images.jpg1",
               "display_type":1
            },
            {
               "url":"https://url.com/images.jpg2",
               "display_type":0
            },
            {
               "url":"https://url.com/images.jpg3",
               "display_type":0
            }
         ],
         "characteristics":[
            {
               "id":7774,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":7947,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":8001,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":8937,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":8930,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":8927,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":8928,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":5537,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":8932,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":8934,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":8929,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":7235,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":6556,
               "value":"val"
            },
            {
               "id":5401,
               "value":"val"
            }
         ],
         "attachments":[

         ],
         "vat_id":1,
         "family":{
            "id":123456,
            "name":"Name",
            "family_type_id":244
         },
         "start_date":[

         ],
         "estimated_stock":144,
         "reversible_vat_charging":false,
         "min_sale_price":11,
         "max_sale_price":200,
         "offer_details":{
            "id":242414,
            "warranty_type":null,
            "supply_lead_time":14
         },
         "offer_properties":[

         ],
         "product_measurements":[

         ],
         "availability":[
            {
               "warehouse_id":1,
               "id":3
            }
         ],
         "stock":[
            {
               "warehouse_id":1,
               "value":9
            }
         ],
         "handling_time":[
            {
               "warehouse_id":1,
               "value":0
            }
         ],
         "barcode":[

         ],
         "ean":[

         ],
         "commission":{
            "value":"20.0000",
            "type":"percentage",
            "id":"12492",
            "priority":"4",
            "created":"2010-01-16 11:25:02"
         },
         "validation_status":[
            {
               "value":9,
               "description":"Approved documentation",
               "errors":null
            }
         ],
         "offer_validation_status":{
            "value":1,
            "description":"Saleable",
            "errors":null
         },
         "ownership":1,
         "best_offer_sale_price":77.31,
         "best_offer_recommended_price":83.19,
         "number_of_offers":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the output of the conversion

```
part_number_key,buy_button_rank,category_id,id,brand,vendor_category_id,name,part_number,sale_price,currency,description,url,warranty,general_stock,weight,status,recommended_price,images,characteristics,attachments,vat_id,family,start_date,estimated_stock,reversible_vat_charging,min_sale_price,max_sale_price,offer_details,offer_properties,product_measurements,availability,stock,handling_time,barcode,ean,commission,validation_status,offer_validation_status,ownership,best_offer_sale_price,best_offer_recommended_price,number_of_offers
DASDSA,1,11,123,brand,,Name,"part number",12.31,RON,description,https://www.url.com,12,10,0,1,12.19,Array,Array,Array,1,Array,Array,10,,11,200,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,1,11,11,1
D3129DKQW,1,456,123,Bluedio,,name,"part number",123,EUR,description,https://url.com,24,1,0,1,12,Array,Array,Array,1,Array,Array,144,,11,200,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,1,77.31,83.19,1
```

As you can see, there is array instead of values, can someone tell me why?

I tried reset() function but I get only the value from the first column ( part_number_key )

```
foreach ($json as $line){  
   if (empty($firstLineKeys))   {  
      $firstLineKeys = array_keys($line); print_r("aici3"); fputcsv($f,
      $firstLineKeys); print_r("aici3"); $firstLineKeys = array_flip($firstLineKeys);
   }   fputcsv($f,
   array_merge($firstLineKeys,
   $line)); $first = reset($line); print_r($first);
}
```

I want to extract all columns but to show only the first row value from every from every column, for example at "images" column I would like to extract just the first url and same for the rest of columns

And one more thing, what is the best method to ignore few columns?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because the images and characteristics, etc, are arrays. If you want to get the values, you'll have to pull that data out individually as well.

Comment: How would the result look for multiple values in the inner array?

Comment: @Nico Haase  The best way would be to extract the first value but I don't know how...

Comment: Well, that would be `$array[0]` then or `reset($array)` - but wouldn't you lose a lot of data then?

Comment: @cristialexandru - `$first = reset($array);`

Comment: Should probably `implode()` that column before adding it to the array

Comment: Please add all attempts to the question, not to the comment section. Additionally, explain further what the expected output should be

Comment: @NicoHaase Updated, sorry!